# Endorsement in Hyperledger Fabric

Tags: hyperledger-fabric

I just start learning Hyperledger Fabric and I am kind of confused by the endorsement. I am not sure how endorsing peers validate a transaction.

For example, Org A and Org B are trading cars. Org A submitted an owner transfer transaction to change the owner of a car from Org B to Org A. However, Org B doesn't know about this (Org A is submitting a transaction that never happens physically). With an endorsement policy AND(orgA.member, orgB.member), once the submitter's (Org A's client) identity is valid, the endorsing peer of Org B will still endorse this transaction even Org B has no idea what is happening. The ledger still got changed.

How Hyperledger Fabric makes sure the transaction is happening in the real world? I was thinking Org B can perform some extra checks on this kind of transaction.

Thank you.

Comment: *endorsement policy AND(orgA.member, orgB.member)*, means that the transaction needs both orgA and orgB to sign into the transaction to make it valid. The ledger is changed, but the transaction will be marked as failed

Comment: But org B will still sign the transaction no matter what Org A submits right?

Comment: It depends on the logic in your chaincode. For example, you define the ownerTransfer() func with a precheck that the transaction must satisfy *the submitter == car owner*